# ingress mariadb always return This site can’t be reached

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm just learning about Kubernetes using ingress and MariaDB. I don't know which one make my code error that return "This site can’t be reached". The requirement including Services, ConfigMap, and Secret. Make sure it is exposed by Ingress (make a simple local DNS in /etc/hosts) and can be accessed by Postman / Web Browser (do not port forwarding). All the CRUD features (Article) must be included in the video demo.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: toto-mariadb-volume
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: toto-mariadb-volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: toto-mariadb-secret
stringData:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: toto
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd
  MYSQL_USER: toto_user
data:
  toto_VERY_SECRET: "a3ViZXJuZXRlcwo="

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: toto-mariadb-config
data:
  APP_NAME: "toto-mariadb"
  APP_PORT: "3306"

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: toto-mariadb
  labels:
    app: toto-mariadb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: toto-mariadb
  template:
    metadata:
      name: toto-mariadb
      labels:
        app: toto-mariadb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: toto-mariadb
          image: mariadb
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              protocol: TCP
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: toto-mariadb-secret
            - configMapRef:
                name: toto-mariadb-config

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: toto-mariadb-service
spec:
  selector:
    name: toto-mariadb
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
      protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: toto-mariadb-ingress
  labels:
    app: toto-mariadb-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: toto-mariadb.lovanto.local
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: toto-mariadb-service
            port: 
              number: 3306
```

The code work properly when using port-forward, but when using the host still not working

Answer (score 0):

Ingress is HTTP only. Most if not all databases, including MariaDB, don't use http as protocol.

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress):

> An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type Service.Type=NodePort or Service.Type=LoadBalancer.

You could expose this as a TCP service, if your ingress controller supports it. For example, see this: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

Comment: when I try it the endpoint going null and still doesn't work

Comment: @JustLovanto, perhaps you do some mistakes along the way. As it stands you cannot use ingress for mariadb. I have quoted and linked the docs saying this.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB **does not use** the HTTP protocol which is what `postman` and a `browser` use. Ingress are only concerned with http/https. So for your use case **you most likely do not need an ingress**.

There are a couple of easy ways to handle this.

#### kubectl port-forward ...

---

If you are just using this for fun/learning a quick way is to use port-forward using `kubectl` for example:

```
kubectl port-forward service/toto-mariadb-service 3306:3306
```

Then you would use an app/client like [MariaDB Client](https://mariadb.com/products/skysql/docs/connect/clients/mariadb-client/) to access the db using `localhost` at port `3306`. You could also make a `/etc/hosts` entry with `127.0.0.1 <your-desired-hostname>`

read more on this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod

#### Service of type: LoadBalancer

---

This is a better way if you want to have a port easily available long term to connect to. You will need to add `type: LoadBalancer` to the spec of your service (see below for example).

By default if `type:` is omitted from the service's spec field it will default to `type: ClusterIP` which will only assign an ip from the `serviceCidr` range which is not accessible from outside the cluster.

The potential problem with this approach is if you cluster is not configured to provide you an `external ip` when you `kubectl get svc ...` the external ip column will stay stuck at pending. If this happens to you you will need to see what methods will work for your flavor of K8s. A common approach is to use [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: toto-mariadb-service
spec:
  selector:
    name: toto-mariadb
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Then you would use your app/client to talk to the `external ip` the service has. Get this ip from your service with `kubectl get svc ...`

read more on this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer